# Why is sqlite delete table thousands of times slower from python than the sqlite3 shell?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database (version 3.31.1). It has a table X that has ~35 million rows (each with 3 columns). It also has one index. I am trying to delete this table in two different ways (on Windows 10):

1. Using the sqlite shell "sqlite> DELETE FROM X;" --> this takes **a minute or two**.
2. Using my python application, with the sqlite3 library (Python 3.9.1) --> this didn't finish after I let it run for **5 hours**:

```
# "self" here is a class that holds the database connection
self.conn = sqlite3.connect("dbfile.db")
self.run_sql_command("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")
self.run_sql_command("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;")
cursor = self.conn.cursor()
result = cursor.execute("DELETE FROM X;")   # This is where it stalls for hours
self.conn.commit()
```

You can see in the code above that I am using WAL mode ("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;"), although when I changed to this, it only sped up the shell version and doesn't seem to have done anything for the python version. I also know that the python approach works fast enough on smaller scale statements (DELETE but also other statements like INSERT and SELECT with joins etc).

Is there anything in using the python approach that can lead to such a dramatic difference for the exact same large-scale DELETE statement?

Comment: Did you turn on foreign keys in the shell first? Does your table have keys that are used as foreign keys by other tables or vis versa?

Comment: No, I did not have foreign keys in the shell. And yes, I definitely have keys that are used as foreign keys across tables (because there is an ID that is shared across almost all the tables). It sounds like you think that might be responsible?

Comment: Yeah, that would likely be why. A lot less work dealing with ON DELETE clauses and checking to see if the row can be deleted or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shawn's comment to the question is the answer, so I'm just putting it here as the accepted answer. I tested by wrapping the deleting code in one statement disabling foreign keys ("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;") and then re-enabling it after deleting, and the Python implementation was just as fast. Thanks Shawn!